# What is the true need of sequence in Sql Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 (Denali), we have a new feature **Sequence**. Consider the below program

```
/****** Create Sequence Object ******/
CREATE SEQUENCE GenerateSequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

/****** Create a test Table ******/
Create TABLE tblTest
(
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Age int NOT NULL
);

/****** Insert Some Records ******/
INSERT INTO tblTest(ID, Name, Age)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR GenerateSequence, 'Name1',10),
(NEXT VALUE FOR GenerateSequence, 'Name2',20),
(NEXT VALUE FOR GenerateSequence, 'Name3',30),
(NEXT VALUE FOR GenerateSequence, 'Name4',40);

/****** Display result******/
SELECT * FROM tblTest;
```

Output

```
ID Name     Age
1  Name1    10
2  Name2    20
3  Name3    30
4  Name4    40
```

Instead of this we can use an identity column like

```
Create TABLE tblTest
(
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY Identity,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Age int NOT NULL
);
```

and can populate like

```
INSERT INTO tblTest(Name, Age)
VALUES ('Name1',10),
VALUES ('Name2',20)...
```

etc. to get the same output

Then what extra benifit we will achieve by using sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be used between different database tables, so that it keeps the ID unique between multiple tables.

Have a look at [SQL Sequences and Create Sequence of Numbers in SQL Server 2011](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/number-of-sequences-in-sql-server-2011-using-sequence-objects.aspx)

> A SQL Server sequence object generates
>   sequence of numbers just like an
>   identity column in sql tables. But the
>   advantage of sequence numbers is the
>   sequence number object is not limited
>   with single sql table.

Comment: Seriously - SQL Server is getting sequences?!  SNOOPY DANCE!

Comment: To avoid the manual generation of these kindsa IDs I assume... X-)